# Symfony deployment using composer Database fails

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

When I make the first deploy of a Symfony App using composer I find an error because 'composer install' command try to clear cache and this process try to update the database schema, but at that point database is not created.

1º composer install
   1a- install vendors
   1b- build parameters
   1c- clear cache
       -> Try to connect with database
2º create database (we need to have vendors installed previously to use de symfony console so we can't swap the order)

How can I fix this? Actually there isn't a big trouble because in the second step database will be created and then in 3rd step we can clear cache without problems, but It is not so smart to see always in the first deploy a big red error message.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the commands you used and the exact error messages. Use pastebin if you have to.

Comment: Only: composer install
That command automatically calls php bin/console cache:clear